# How do I prove this topological space is T2 and compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, separable-spaces

Let $\tau $ be a topology:
$\tau=\{A \subset \mathbb{R}^2 | S^1 \subset(\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus A  ) \}   \cup\{\mathbb{R}^2\}$  where
$S^1=\{  (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x^2+y^2=1  \}$

Prove $\tau$ is a Hausdorff space and that it is compact

The solution I was given for the fist part is: 
if $p \in S^1$, the only neighborhood of $p$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$, then it is not a Hausdorff's space.

I don't get it. the open sets of this topology are disjoint set with the circle $S^1$, so I should not be taking a neighborhood(an open set) on the circle, should I? Can someone elaborate on it and prove compactness as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not  Hausdorff. Take $x \in S^1$,  then the only open set that contains $x$ is $ \mathbb{R}^2$, so for the points in $S^1$, there aren't disjoint open sets containing them. Now that being said, if there is a cover $\mathcal{A}$ for $ \mathbb{R}^2$, then $ \mathbb{R}^2 \in \mathcal{A}$ ( since a point of $S^1$ is in the cover), so it has a finite subcover.

Comment: So it is enought to take a a subcover consisting of only the whole set, right?, since that is the only way to cover S1 but that covers everything already.  May I ask you how to prove connectedness too?. I did that one myself by contradiction, but given that the solutions are so short, I wonder if mine is optimal

Comment: Yes. Sure! Suppose $\mathbb{R}^2 = A \cup B$, where $A,B$ are disjoint open sets. Since $(1,0) \in A$ or $ B$ we conclude that $A$ or $ B$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$, so the other one must the empty set since they are disjoint.